# Find the critical numbers of $g(x)=(x-3)^{2/3}$ and find the open intervals where the function is increasing or decreasing.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Section 3.1 #11:

Find the critical numbers of $g(x)=(x-3)^{2/3}$ and find the open intervals where the function is increasing or decreasing.

$Solution$:

The critical points are the values of $x$ at which either $g'(x)=0$ or $g'(x)$ DNE. So, first we have to find $g'(x)$, and it looks like we are going to have to use the chain rule to do it.

$g'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} (x-3)^{2/3} = \frac{2}{3}(x-3)^{\frac{-1}{3}} = \frac{2}{3(x-3)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$

Okay, first lets find where

$g'(x)= \frac{2}{3(x-3)^{\frac{1}{3}}}=0$

Multiplying both sides of this equation by the denominator:

$(3(x-3)^{\frac{1}{3}})\frac{2}{3(x-3)^{\frac{1}{3}}}=0(3(x-3)^{\frac{1}{3}})$

$\rightarrow$

$2=0$.

Well shoot, that's not right. It looks like the derivative of $g(x)$ never equals zero.

What about the values of $x$ that are critical points because $g'(x)$ DNE? Well, that would be values of $x$ that make the denominator zero, and so we must have $x=3$.

So $x=3$ is our only critical point.

Now we split the number line up into two different sections, all the numbers to the left of $3$ and then all the numbers to the right of $3$, we pick a number from each region and plug it into the derivative to see if the original function of $g(x)$ is increasing or decreasing there.

$g'(0) = \frac{2}{3(0-3)^{\frac{1}{3}}} = \frac{2}{3(-3)^{\frac{1}{3}}}<0$

Note we don't have to know exactly what this number equals, only whether it's positive or negative.

So, since $g'(0)$ was negative, we have $g(x)$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,3)$

Now lets plug in a number to the right of $3$... how about 5.

$g'(5) = \frac{2}{3(5-3)^{\frac{1}{3}}} = \frac{2}{3(3)^{\frac{1}{3}}}>0$

Therefore $g(x)$ is increasing on $(3,\infty)$

Comment: Everything looks fine. The function indeed has a critical point at $x=3$ and is decreasing to the left and increasing to the right of the critical point.

Comment: If your function had been $x^{2/3}$, could you work with that? Qualitatively, it shouldn't look all that different from $\mid x\mid^{1/2}$.